# How to use default account parameters (login/pwd) in Android phone?

Tags: android, credentials

I want to use default Android credentials for specific phone to pass authentication test in Google Apps, but documentation is terrible :-(, and worst of all I'm a newbie.

Anyone have a idea how to do it? 
There are some apache libs for it, but as I mentioned documentation is very weak. [Here is reference to this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/auth/Credentials.html).

best,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean user's Google account and password? If yes then it cannot be done to my knowledge. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the Apache HttpComponents can be found on the [Apache HttpComponents Web site](http://hc.apache.org/).

Specifically, you may be interested in the [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html), such as the client authentication [example](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/ClientAuthentication.java).